# What do you call the "owner" of an idea?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I recently found myself in a situation where I wanted to use a line that went something like this:

> *"...we must examine the effects these ideas had on their respective creators..."*

and I just couldn't find the right word in place of "creators". Something feels off about "creators". We don't create thoughts we *have* thoughts or we *think* thoughts. "Owners" doesn't really work as no one can "own" a thought, and "thinkers" sounds too childish.

What other words are there that describe "the person who came up with an idea"?

Comment: *originators*, *progenitors*?

Comment: @DanBron *originator* might work, though I always thought a *progenitor* was more like an ancestor?

Comment: @user3002473 How about "brainstormer"? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brainstormer

Comment: a *proponent* is not quite the same as the originator of an idea, but certainly proponents can be thought of advocating it, or "owning" it in some loose sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to [conceive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conceive) (verb):

Defn. 2 - Form or devise (a plan or idea) in the mind

> *"the dam project was originally conceived in 1977"*

Derived noun forms include [conceiver](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conceiver) or [conceptor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conceptor)

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conceive)

Comment: @user3002473 you're very welcome and thanks!

Comment: Personally if i read "we must examine the effects these ideas had on their respective conceptors" I would be confused.  To me, "creators" is fine.  This may just be because i've never encountered the word "conceptor" before.  Sometimes, just being in the dictionary doesn't make something the right choice - you need to consider your audience too.,

Comment: I personally would use "conceiver" over "conceptor", even though the latter has a closer dictionary meaning to what the OP wants. "conceiving an idea" is a fairly well-known expression.

Answer (score 3):

"...the effects on those who **brought forth** these ideas must be examined..."

> bring forth
>   1. To give rise to; produce: plants bringing forth fruit.
>   2. To give birth to (young).

brought forth. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved April 4 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brought+forth

Answer (score 2):

**originator** (from [*origin*](https://www.google.com/search?q=origin%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8): the point or place where something begins, arises, or is derived)

> a person who creates or initiates something. *"Wegener was the [originator](https://www.google.com/search?q=originators%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) of the theory of continental drift"* –Google

"...we must examine the effects these ideas had on their respective *originators*..."

Here's an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=originator%2Cconceptor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coriginator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconceptor%3B%2Cc0) showing *conceptor* in its non-existence up against *originator*. Interestingly, only recently has *brought forth* [been surpassed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=originator%2Cconceptor%2Cbrought%20forth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coriginator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconceptor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrought%20forth%3B%2Cc0) by *originator*.

---

As per the title, the "owner" of an IP ([intellectual property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property)) is generally referred to as, *the holder*. However, the average person is more likely to encounter a holder that is using *plaintiff* as their moniker.